# Application of Implicit Function Theorem in Munkres Analysis on Manifolds

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I'm studying the Implicit Function Theorem and this is a problem from Munkres' Analysis on Manifolds.

Let $F:\mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ be of class $C^2$, with $F(0,0)=0$ and $DF(0,0)=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 3\end{bmatrix}$. 
Let $G:\mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by the equation $$G(x,y,z)=F(x+2y+3z-1, x^3+y^2-z^2).$$

(a) Note that $G(-2,3,-1)=F(0,0)=0$. Show that one can solve the equation $G(x,y,z)=0$ for $z$, say $z=g(x,y)$, for $(x,y)$ in a neighborhood $B$ of $(-2,3)$, such that $g(-2,3)=-1$.

(b) Find $Dg(-2,3)$.

(c) If $D_1D_1F=3$ and $D_1D_2F=-1$ and $D_2D_2F=5$ at $(0,0)$, find $D_2D_1g(-2,3)$.

I've worked through (a) and (b). This is my answer.

Define $h(x,y,z)=(x+2y+3z-1,x^3+y^2-z^2)$, then $G=F\circ h$, so by Chain Rule, $DG=DF(h(x,y,z))Dh(x,y,z)$.

Since $Dh=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
3x^2 & 2y & -2z \\
\end{bmatrix},$
then
$DG(-2,3,-1)=\begin{bmatrix}
38 & 22 & 12 \\
\end{bmatrix}$.

So $\frac{\partial G}{\partial z}(-2,3,-1)=12\neq 0$.
Hence by the Implicit Function Theorem, we can find such $g$ and $B$ in (a).

Also, we've got $Dg(-2,3)=\frac{-1}{12}\begin{bmatrix}
38 & 22 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ from the result obtained above.

However, I'm lost on how to approach (c). I'm not sure how I'm supposed to find the value. I would appreciate some help on this problem.

Comment: ? Isn't that very much the same question as in : [Munkres Implicit Function Theorem. If $D_1D_1F = 3$, $D_1D_2F=-1$ and $D_2D_2F=5$ at $(0,0)$, find $D_2D_1g(-2,3)$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2092258/munkres-implicit-function-theorem-if-d-1d-1f-3-d-1d-2f-1-and-d-2d-2f-5)

Comment: The answer linked in the comment is gone.  Was op's answer for b) correct?